# Three.js stl rendering code doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, stl-format

I am trying to render an stl with three js here is my code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        

        <script src="./STLLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
//const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//scene.add( cube );

const loadObject = () => {
    const loader = new STLLoader()
    loader.load("./public/3dbenchy.stl", function (geometry) {
        group = new THREE.Group()
        scene.add(group)

        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 })
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
        mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
        mesh.scale.set(10, 10, 10)
        mesh.castShadow = true
        mesh.receiveShadow = true

        geometry.center()
        group.add(mesh)
    })
}
camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    //cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

animate();
```

I tried to import the package in multiple different ways, but none of them rendered anything. I have also tried multiple different 3-D models but none of them worked either.